# Unable to run carla simltor 0.9.13 in upuntu 20.04

Tags: carla

when i run ./CarlaUE4.sh  i get this error:

chmod: cannot access '/media/tamo/TAMOSSD/carla/CARLA/CarlaUE4/Binaries/Linux/CarlaUE4-Linux-Shipping': No such file or directory
./CarlaUE4.sh: 5: /media/tamo/TAMOSSD/carla/CARLA/CarlaUE4/Binaries/Linux/CarlaUE4-Linux-Shipping: not found

I already checked the files and they exist, also I'm using upuntu20.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the CarlaUE4.sh file is not in executable mode.

Check the executable mode of the file by typing the following command in the terminal

```
ls -l path/to/CarlUE4.sh
```

If the output looks something like this:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 usr 1049089 17222 Jul  1  2020 CarlaUE4.sh
```

The output is explained as follows:

- rw- file owner can read and write to file, but can't execute
- r-- group file owner can only read the file, and can't neither execute nor write to it
- r-- all other users can only read too

To make the file executable do the following:

```
chmod +x path\to\CarlaUE4.sh
```

This will allow all user to execute this file. If you want to allow only certain users/groups to execute the file, refer to [this blog post](https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/it-ops/linux-file-permissions) for a more elaborate answer on changing mode of a file